# activity in the real mobile crashes but in the emulator works

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I had something like this:

```
    private static Context context;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.context = getApplicationContext();
...
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.id1:
                String idp = current_user;
                Intent intentf = new Intent(context, More1.class);
                intentf.putExtra("id", idp);
                context.startActivity(intentf);
                break;

            case R.id.id2:
                String idp2 = current_user;
                Intent intentff = new Intent(context, More2.class);
                intentff.putExtra("id", idp2);
                context.startActivity(intentff);
                break;

        }
    }
```

it worked in my emulator but not in my real mobile.
So I changed context to this and it works both.

But somehow it worry me, because my app can crash in some devices and not in others...

any ideas why my app crashes in real phone and not in emulator using:

```
            Intent intentf = new Intent(context, More1.class);
            intentf.putExtra("id", idp);
            context.startActivity(intentf);
```

but will not crash using:

```
                Intent intentf = new Intent(this, More1.class);
                intentf.putExtra("id", idp);
                this.startActivity(intentf);
```

Comment: What is error message, what happens when it crashes? Provide more information.

Comment: Please provide the log..

Comment: it crashes in my real phone only (the app closes), so I hadn't log because in the emulator it works. But if I change context to this will work in both. my question here is just to know why it crashes in my real phone using context and not in emulator.

Comment: with the use of getApplicationContext() this problem occurs in many device. So try to use YourActivity.this in place of getApplicationContext()